# How to call Scala functions in Jade?

Tags: scala, jetty

I am learning [Jade](https://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/jade-syntax.html), which is `the daddy of HTML template engines for Scala`.

My servlet:

```
package com.test.web

class StatusServlet extends HttpServlet {

  var mystatus: MyStatus = _

  override def init(config: ServletConfig) {
    this.mystatus = getMyStatus(config.getServletContext())
  }

  override def doGet(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) = {
    req.setAttribute("mystatus", Option(mystatus))
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/status.jade").forward(req, resp)
  }
}
```

My jade file:

```
- import com.test.MyStatus

-@val mystatus: Option[MyStatus] = None

html
  head
    link(href="../css/site.css" rel="stylesheet")
  body
    h2 This is for testing
    table
      tr
        td status is
        td= mystatus.map(_.isWriteEnabled)
```

`isWriteEnabled` is a function which returns boolean.

I am new to [jade](https://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/jade-syntax.html) and jetty. the above code looks good to me. but in the UI, `mystatus.map(_.isWriteEnabled)` is not displayed (it is `<td></td>`). No values displayed.

Any hints welcomed. Thanks